# How to strtotime date format like this

Tags: php

I would like to strtotime dateformat like this - Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012 How could I do that? Basically I need to strtotime it, then do the following - `$ago = time()-strtotime(Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012);` and then do this -

```
$ago = $ago / (60*60*24);
echo $ago.' days ago';
```

So I need one thing - strtotime(Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012) which will work as it need to work.

If this type of date cannot be strtotime, then how can I edit it, so it could be strtotime?

Comment: [See this](http://is2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: huh? so you want to input a date like Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012 and have it return '4 days ago'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the difference and use floor/ceil to round.

```
$now = time();
$then = strtotime($var);

echo floor(($now - $then) / 86400) . " days ago";
```

Comment: Yikes! Does `strotime("Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012")` return what you *think* it should?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (OOP style, there's a procedural equivalent):

```
<?php
$str = "Fri Jun 15 05:38:11 +1000 2012";

// From here: http://is2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s T Y', $str);
$now = new DateTime();

// From here: http://is2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
$interval = $now->diff($datetime);
echo $interval->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime::createFromFormat()` method allows you to define the format of the date string that you wish to parse.